# Kivy.Clock , how to return and access variable returned from a scheduled method?

Tags: python, oop, kivy

I want something like this, but it doesn't work

```
class SomeClass():   

    def somedelaymethod(self, timearg):
        returnedvalue = Clock.schedule_once(self.somescheduledmethod, timearg)
        return returnedvalue

    def somescheduledmethod(self, dt):
        value = something
        return value
```

How can i access the return value returned by a scheduled function?

Comment: You can't structure your code like this, the Clock call doesn't block and wait to return a value. If you can't see an alternative way to do this, post a full minimal runnable example demonstrating what you want to happen and want to achieve in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a delayable function for this (you will need [kivyoav](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/kivyoav))

```
from kivyoav.delayed import delayable    
class SomeClass():
    @delayable #<------- !!!
    def somedelaymethod(self, timearg):
        yield timearg #will cause the wanted delay without making the UI unresponsive
        returnedvalue = self.somescheduledmethod()
        #do somthing with returnvalue...


    def somescheduledmethod(self):
        value = something
        return value
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a callback is a good way to achieve this. Something like:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        label = Label(text='Waiting...')

        def callback(value):
            label.text = "Got {0}".format(value)

        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.somescheduledmethod(callback), 1)
        return label

    def somescheduledmethod(self, callback):
        value = 'something'
        callback(value)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the value to an instance attribute on `self`.  If you need something further to happen you could do it before returning or make the attribute a Kivy property.

Answer (score -1):

Your class has parenthesis, which it shouldn't. That does not have anything to do with your question, but it is important.

To access the return value, you need to make an instance of your class, and run the function through the instance.

```
class SomeClass:
    #what you wrote goes here

a = SomeClass() #you put parenthesis here, but not above.
print(a.whateverMethodYouWantToUse())
```

And it prints the return value of the method. I hope this answered what you were asking.

Comment: Fair enough,  I was going to put (SomeInheritance)  but for quickness I missed it out,  forgot to remove brackets because I was asking in quickness.  This doesn't answer the question however as kivy.clock behaves differently, and I want  to access the method through the scheduled clock not in the way you indicated,  but  thanks anyway